# Applescript selection name extension

Tags: applescript

i got problem for the name extension of selection
it not work when i select more then 2 different files type
please help

```
property doc_list : {"pdf", "doc"}

property image_list : {"jpg", "png", "tif", "tiff", "gif"}


tell application "Finder"


    set sel to (get selection)
    repeat with AnItem in sel
    end repeat
    if sel = {} then
        display alert ("nothing selected")

    else if name extension of AnItem is in doc_list then

        display alert ("this is doc files")

    else if name extension of AnItem is in image_list then

        display alert ("this is images files")

    else if name extension of AnItem is in image_list & doc_list then

        display alert ("this is images and doc files")

    else if name extension of AnItem is not in image_list & doc_list then

        display alert ("unknown file type")


    end if


end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `end repeat` line must be moved to before `end tell`.

This is a slightly improved version. The third `else if` clause will never be reached and the fourth can be just `else`

```
property doc_list : {"pdf", "doc"}

property image_list : {"jpg", "png", "tif", "tiff", "gif"}

tell application "Finder"
    set sel to (get selection)
    if sel = {} then
        display alert ("nothing selected")
        return
    end if
    repeat with AnItem in sel
        set nameExtension to name extension of AnItem
        if nameExtension is in doc_list then
            display alert ("this is doc files")
        else if nameExtension is in image_list then
            display alert ("this is images files")
        else
            display alert ("unknown file type " & quote & nameExtension & quote)
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: thks Vadian, but this version got problem of alert, if i selected 5 files it will repeat 5 times alert , how to fix it ?

Comment: How to fix what? You got a list of items and you can process the items only one by one.

Comment: thks Vadian , please ignore , got new problem for the selection order , the code only work for the 1st selected files